# Reading from MySQL database won't work

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT hour, team1, team2, goalsteam1, goalsteam2, competition FROM `matches` WHERE `date`='". $daterow['date'] ."'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){    

    $hour = substr($row['hour'],0,5);

    $teamemblem = mysql_query("SELECT emblem FROM `teams` WHERE `team`='".$row['team1']."'");
    $teamemblemrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($teamemblem);

    echo '
        <tr class="teamtable">
            <td style="width:60px; font-size:11px;">'.$hour.'</td>
            <td style="width:145px; font-size:11px;"><img width=24px height=24px src='.$teamemblemrow['teamemblem'].'/></td>
            <td style="width:15px; font-size:11px;">'.$row['goalsteam1'].'</td>
            <td style="width:15px; font-size:11px;">'.$row['goalsteam2'].'</td>
            <td style="width:145px; font-size:11px;">'.$row['team2'].'</td>
            <td style="width:120; font-size:11px;">'.$row['competition'].'</td>
        </tr>'; 
}
```

I tried everything, but the emblem part won't work. It refuses to read from the database. Thing is printing `$row['team1']` works, but I don't get why it just won't read..

Any help?

Comment: PS The problem is that the emblem `<img>` doesn't display because `$teamemblemrow['teamemblem']` is empty for some reason

Comment: Your select asks for `emblem`, so it probably needs to be `$teamemblemrow['emblem']` not `$teamemblemrow['teamemblem']`

Comment: +1 for using in-line style and mysql_* extension in the year 2014

Comment: ZombieHunter idgaf really about what you say about my style lol

Comment: Just a suggestion for the future: if you have a seemingly simple problem, try using the function `var_dump()` or `print_r()` on the problematic variable and see what you come up with. Not that your questions aren't welcome, but it likely would have saved you a good deal of time not having to post a question and wait for replies. You mentioned below that you are still new to PHP, so obviously I'm not faulting you. Just providing a tip for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query you do the select as :

```
SELECT emblem FROM `teams` WHERE...
```

But in your code you refer to it after as:

```
$teamemblemrow['teamemblem']
```

Which is it? `emblem` or `teamemblem`?

When you return an assoc array, you need to make sure that you refer to the elements by the same name. If you want to use a different name, you can modify your query to bring the field back as a different name like this:

```
SELECT emblem as teamemblem FROM `teams` WHERE...
```

Which then means you can refer to the assoc array returned via what y ou have in your code at the moment.

Edit: Additionally, you are using old `mysql_*` functions. You really should have a read of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) and upgrade your code to much better functions.

Comment: omg! What a noob mistake.. Thanks a lot! This fixed, I had to put emblem not teamemblem. Well not scripting for 1 month does this. Thanks a lot. Going to accept your answer in 8 mins

Comment: @hydravink That's okay, we all miss these things sometime and a fresh set of eyes can sometimes spot them in seconds :)

Comment: _“Well not scripting for 1 month does this”_ – no, not having proper error_reporting enabled does this – so __do that now!__